# Translate OpenCl code for CPU compilation

Tags: numpy, opencl, cython, pyopencl

Sometimes I find myself writing OpenCl kernel code (using pyopencl), even for tasks which involve moderate computational complexity, because it is easier to develop than a chain of numpy operations (especially if no appropriate numpy function exists).

However, in those cases the transfer overhead/delay between host and device may exceed the time spend for computation.

I was thinking about creating some Python tool, which automatically translates the OpenCl code to e.g. Cython code (or similar) which, after compilation for the CPU, can directly work on the underlying memory of the numpy arrays, without the need to copy the data to the device. I know that the CPU is capable of executing OpenCl kernels with appropriate drivers. However, this still has the disadvantages of additional delay due to the `to_device` operation. A multicore CPU could also exploit the OpenCL programming model for parallel execution. Furthermore, this approach removes the need for special OpenCl drivers and just requires some build tools for C-Code compilation.

Is that a reasonable idea? I do not want to reinvent the wheel. Any hints for existing frameworks/tools which could achieve my goals are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

While converting an OpenCL code to a parallel CPU-oriented code is probably possible, it very hard (if not possible) to generate an efficient code.

Indeed, OpenCL encourage/force programmers to perform big computational steps (kernels) often reading/writing a relatively big portion of memory. However, the GPUs memory bandwidth is generally much higher than the one of CPUs (eg. my Nvidia 1660S has a bandwidth of 336 GB/s while my i5-9600KF with 2 DD4 channel succeed to reach about 40 GB/s while they had a similar price). OpenCL computing kernels are not be fully optimized for CPUs whatever the low-level transformation applied to the code. The main problem lies in the OpenCL algorithms themselves as well as the programming model. Rewriting OpenCL kernels to a CPU code can often result in a more efficient execution if the code is specifically optimized for such a platform. Low-level optimizations include working on in caches using *data chunks*, using register blocking, using the best SIMD instructions available. High-level optimizations consist in choosing the best algorithm and data structure for the target problem. The best *sorting algorithm* on a GPU is likely very different from the best one on a CPU. The same thing applies for other problems like computing a *prefix sum*, a *partition/median* or even string searching. Thus, one should keep in mind that **different hardwares required different computing methods/algorithms**.

A high-level algorithmic transformation could theoretically result in an efficient code, but such a transformation is insanely complex to perform if even possible. Indeed, there is [fundamental theoretical limitations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis) that strongly prevent many generalized advanced code analysis/transformation starting from the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) to [high-level optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler).